# << operation in byte array processing

Tags: java

I am a little bit confused to understand the ´>>´ operation in this method below. Does the programmer try to get the first and second byte from the byte data array without modifying the content of the data array? And what does the hte 255 (ff) mean to the operation?

I appreciate any help.

**simple**

```
public static int get2ByteData(final int[] data) {
    int number = 0;
    number += (data[0] & 0xff) << 8;
    number += (data[1] & 0xff) << 0;
    return number;
}
```

Comment: `0xff` is `11111111` in binary. It's used as a bitmask to isolate the 8 least significant bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just some bitmasking/shifting operations.

e.g. if `data[0]` contains these bits `1111000010101010`, then here's what happens:

```
      1111000010101010
&&    0xFF

      1111000010101010
&&    0000000011111111
----------------------
      0000000010101010


      0000000010101010
<< 8
----------------------
      1010101000000000
```

Ditto for `data[1]`, except since the bitshift is 0, there's no shifting occuring.

Basically, this code is taking a 16bit number, and swapping the bytes around, so that bitpattern `xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyy` becomes `yyyyyyyyxxxxxxxx`